# Javascript scope issue

Tags: javascript, scoping

I thought I understood how javascript scope worked until now. This is what I have

```
function MFCommentsHandler(node, type, item) {
    this.get = function(returnType){
        ...
    }

    function getButton(){
        var button = document.createElement('button'),
            get = this.get;
        button.innerHTML = 'Load more comments';
        button.onclick = function(){
            console.log(get);
            get('html');
        }
        return button;
    }

}
```

I use inner functions to append the element generated by `getButton` to the document, but when I click it I get `get is not a function`. Why is `get` undefined inside of the `onclick` function?

Comment: Are you making get global?

Comment: because `this` is whatever context you're calling `MFCommentsHandler` in. Unless you're constructing a new object using `new`.

Comment: In your case I would just use var get = function...

Comment: @StephenThomas– *this* has nothing to do with "context", it is set entirely by how a function is called or by *bind*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` depends only on **how you call a function**. It can be implicit, but in your case, you lost the context. You need to cache `this` in the upper scope:

```
function MFCommentsHandler(node, type, item) {
    var self = this;
    this.get = function(returnType){
        ...
    }
    function getButton(){
        self.get(); // cached reference
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you can explicitly pass the context when you call `getButton`:

```
function MFCommentsHandler(node, type, item) {
    this.get = function(returnType){
        ...
    }
    function getButton(){
        this.get();
        ...
    }
    getButton.call(this); // explicit context
    ...
```

Comment: Ah.. Such a simple mistake.. Thank you sir.

Comment: "*this depends only how you call a function*". Exactly. "*but in your case, you lost the context*". Which conflicts with the first statement. What you mean is *this* isn't set to the required value in the call.

Comment: What I mean is that `this` isn't what it was before so "you lost context", but technically, yes, it's because `this` is not set in the call. But the call can be implicit, as in `obj.method()`, but you can call the function without dot notation, thus you "lose context". That's how I'd explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The referant of `this` changes with context. Try this instead:

```
function MFCommentsHandler(node, type, item) {
    var get = function(returnType){
        ...
    }

    function getButton(){
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'Load more comments';
        button.onclick = function(){
            console.log(get);
            get('html');
        }
        return button;
    }

}
```

Comment: but then I won't be able to call `get` from the outside

Comment: @php_nub_qq That's true. In that case go with elclanrs's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `getButton()` function you defined inside the `MFCommentsHandler()` function you defined is a closure. Closures have access to the variables and arguments (but not the `arguments` object) of their outer function. They however, do not have access to the `this` value of their outer function. To have access to this value, just store a reference of it in a variable so it can be accessed from the inner function.

```
function MFCommentsHandler(node, type, item) {
    var that = this; //reference to the invocation context
    //that can be accessed anywhere within this function

    this.get = function(returnType){
        ...
    }

    function getButton(){
        ...
        that.get('html');
    }

}
```